# Mailchimp API and mc:repeatable

Tags: mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0, mailchimp-api-v3

I'm working with the MailChimp Transactional API but am having an issue populating an email template that uses a mc:repeatable section. I can't find any docs or examples on how to do this. Here is the endpoint im using https://mailchimp.com/developer/transactional/api/messages/send-using-message-template/

And here is my email template

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Your Order</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div>Thanks for your order</div>
  <div>Your receipt for your order from</div>
  <div mc:edit="store_name">Store Name</div>
  <div>Order Type</div>
  <div mc:edit="order_type">Type</div>  
  <div>Products:</div>  
  <table>
    <tr mc:repeatable="products">     
      <td mc:edit="quantity">Quantity</td>
      <td mc:edit="product_name">Product Name</td>
      <td mc:edit="price">Price</td>
    </tr> 
  
  </table>  

</body>
</html>
```

I'm able to populate all of the `mc:edit` areas using this as the `template_content` in the request body:

```
const content = [
                {
                    name: 'store_name',
                    content: 'Any Store Name'
                },
                {
                    name: 'order_type',
                    content: 'Pickup Order'
                },
                {
                    name: 'subtotal',
                    content: '$80.00'
                },
                {
                    name: 'taxes',
                    content: '$2.22'
                },
                {
                    name: 'fees',
                    content: '$0.00'
                },
                {
                    name: 'total',
                    content: '$82.22'
                }
            ]
```

I can even populate a SINGLE row in the repeatable section if I add objects for `quantity`, `product_name` and `price` but I need to be able to REPEAT this section and add multiple quantity > product name > price lines.

Any advice or help or docs would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [MailChimp template language reference](https://templates.mailchimp.com/getting-started/template-language/), it doesn't appear that `<tr>` elements are supported by `mc:repeatable`. See the third (bolded) point and note that, while `<table>` *is* a block level element, [`<tr>` *is not*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements).

> **mc:repeatable**
>
> - `mc:repeatable` is used to provide a duplication action for a particular element within a template.
> - Syntax: `mc:repeatable`.
> - **Use `mc:repeatable` on block-level elements (like `<div>` and `<p>`) with the exception of lists, or inline elements (like `<img>`, `<a>`, and `<span>`).**
> - `mc:repeatable` elements can be nested within each other, but use care if you’re going to do this. We don’t encourage this use.
> - `mc:repeatable` can be used on the same element as `mc:edit`, but nesting `mc:repeatable` beneath `mc:edit` will render content that is editable but not repeatable.
> - If you want to apply styles to repeatable container elements or elements within repeatable containers, either use class or apply them in-line. Don’t use the id attribute.

---

If they do happen to work, you might need to use `mc:variant` and per-product names for the subfields. Something like this:

```html
<table>
    <tr mc:repeatable="products" mc:variant="product1">
        <td mc:edit="product1_quantity">Quantity</td>
        <td mc:edit="product1_product_name">Product Name</td>
        <td mc:edit="product1_price">Price</td>
    </tr>
    <tr mc:repeatable="products" mc:variant="product2">
        <td mc:edit="product2_quantity">Quantity</td>
        <td mc:edit="product2_product_name">Product Name</td>
        <td mc:edit="product2_price">Price</td>
    </tr>
    <tr mc:repeatable="products" mc:variant="product3">
        <td mc:edit="product3_quantity">Quantity</td>
        <td mc:edit="product3_product_name">Product Name</td>
        <td mc:edit="product3_price">Price</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

```js
const content = [
    {
        name: 'product1_quantity',
        content: '5'
    }, {
        name: 'product1_name',
        content: 'Some Product'
    }, {
        name: 'product1_price',
        content: '$49.99'
    }, 

    {
        name: 'product2_quantity',
        content: '1'
    }, {
        name: 'product2_name',
        content: 'Some Other Product'
    }, {
        name: 'product2_price',
        content: '$1,200'
    },

    {
        name: 'product3_quantity',
        content: '13'
    }, {
        name: 'product3_name',
        content: 'Some Third Product'
    }, {
        name: 'product3_price',
        content: '$17.50'
    }
];
```

---

If this looks like it isn't for building a list from dynamic data, that's because I don't think it is. It looks like it's a [tool for easily getting styles into the Campaign Builder](https://mailchimp.com/help/repeatable-or-variable-content-blocks/).

Inside the builder, there is a `Product` concept that includes the kind of information you appear to want to send in your email. [The tutorial for the builder](https://mailchimp.com/help/design-an-email-new-builder/#heading+product) indicates that while a `Product` section is repeatable, you need to have a source of data connected to the builder and must choose the `Products` to include at design time.

> Use Product content blocks to add items from your [connected online store](https://mailchimp.com/help/connect-your-online-store-to-mailchimp/). Each block is designed to contain a product name, custom description, price, and call-to-action button. And if you turn on e-commerce tracking in your email settings, your report will show purchase revenue.
>
> To use a Product block, follow these steps.
>
> 1. Click a Product block or add one to your email. If you’re working with an existing block, skip to step 4.
> 2. In the Select a store modal, choose the store you want to add products from. If you haven’t yet connected a store, you’ll be prompted to do so.
> 3. Click the product you want to add.
> 4. In the Products menu, edit the Title, Button, and Link to URL as needed. You can also click the edit icon to choose a different product, or click the settings icon to check your store connection.